# Terraform not accepting block parameters on "web_app" Module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a web app through Terraform, the new azurerm provider 3.0 has come out and so the new module azurerm_windows_web_app. The documentation states that the block application_stack supports the following: current_stack, docker, Java, etc.

azurerm version = "=3.0.0"

Link to documentation of Terraform: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app#example-usage

Once I try to run the module created for this, it throws an error:

Error: Unsupported block type

Blocks of type "application_stack" are not expected here.
[image]

Here is a snippet of my code, I am not sure what is going on. Tried to google it but it seems to new to have documentation from other users. Any insight?

```
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "web_app_resource" {
   name                = var.resource_name
   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
   location            = var.location
   service_plan_id     = var.app_service_plan_id
   https_only = true
   tags = var.tags
   count = var.create

   site_config {}

   application_stack {
      current_stack = var.current_stack
      dotnet_version = var.dotnet_version
   }

 }
```

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: Can you add the terraform and provider versions to the question?

Comment: Sure, azurerm is version = "=3.0.0"

Comment: Can you set it to `3.0.2` and try again?

Comment: Still the same issue after the version change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we check the [resource schema](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v3.0.2/internal/services/appservice/windows_web_app_resource.go) for the  `windows_web_app` resource at version 3.0.2 of the provider, then we see that it is currently missing a definition for the `application_stack` attribute. It also seems to be missing other blocks specified in the documentation.

You need to file an issue for your error as this is a bug in the provider.

Update: As this answer is now the victim of sock puppets revisiting, it should be noted `application_stack` is now a nested block in the `site_config` block from its schema. Deleting the answer once un-accepted to avoid further issues.

Comment: It is nested under "site_config" so this answer is incorrect

Answer (score 9):

Block `application_stack` must be nested under `site_config`. JKirk comment is correct.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "default" {

  name                = var.resource_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  service_plan_id     = var.app_service_plan_id

  site_config {

    # Correct placement
    application_stack {
      python_version = 3.9
    }

  }
}
```